# How to detect Konva.Transformer anchor type in transform event

Tags: konvajs, konva

Is there any way to get anchor type ("middle-left", "middle-right", etc) in transform event of Konva.Transformer?

Thanks.

I need to add textnode(Konva.Text) actions when "middle-right" and "bottom-right" transform events.
So I need to detect anchor type in transform event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transformer.getActiveAnchor()` method https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Transformer.html#getActiveAnchor.

```js
const tr = new Konva.Transformer({
  nodes: [node]
})
layer.add(tr);

tr.on('transformstart', () => {
  console.log(tr.getActiveAnchor());
});
```